# Switch to a different app bar on scroll flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an custom app bar which I created using various widgets. The app bar has a background image and some buttons like follow, about etc.

I used it in the page like this:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(180),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: SingleMerchantAppBar(),
        ),
      ),
      extendBody: false,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: _buildItems(context),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: ChatButton(),
    );
  }
```

My custom app bar: `SingleMerchantAppBar`. But I need to change the entire app bar when the user scrolls up.

Let's call the second app bar `AnotherSingleMerchantAppBar`. This app is pretty similar to the default app bar but with no background image and changes in button colors.

My SingleMerchantAppBar can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/u0JkXUpw).

The requirements are:

Default App Bar:

[image]

After scroll app bar:

[image]

I tried sliver app bar but it makes the app bar small and only the text remains as from the examples I've seen so far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a ScrollController to listen, when a User is scrolling. For example:

```
class ChangingAppBar extends StatefulWidget {
  ChangingAppBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChangingAppBarState createState() => _ChangingAppBarState();
}

class _ChangingAppBarState extends State<ChangingAppBar> {
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  double _scrollPosition = 0;

  _scrollListener() {
    setState(() {
      _scrollPosition = _scrollController.position.pixels;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _scrollPosition == 0
          ? AppBar(
              title: const Text('1st AppBar'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            )
          : AppBar(
              title: const Text('2nd AppBar'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        controller: _scrollController,
        itemCount: 20,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text('Item: $index'),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

--- some added edit ---

If you want a more smooth transition, here is one idea:

I understand you might want to fade out an image from the AppBar, not just - bang - replace it. I put an Icon in place of your image, and then it's faded out, with AnimatedOpacity. (There's no limit what you can fade out. You could put two AppBars above each other and then fade out to top one.)

```
class _ChangingAppBarState extends State<ChangingAppBar> {
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  double _scrollPosition = 0;

  _scrollListener() {
    setState(() {
      _scrollPosition = _scrollController.position.pixels;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size(800.0, 100.0),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            AnimatedOpacity(
                opacity: _scrollPosition == 0 ? 1 : 0,
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                child: const Center(child: Icon(Icons.ac_unit_sharp))),
            const Positioned.fill(
              child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text('My Super App'),
                  )),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        controller: _scrollController,
        itemCount: 20,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text('Item: $index'),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You could use the _scrollPosition also for a nicer, smoother transition, obviously.

Comment: The app bar is now changing, Thanks a lot. Can you provide some reference to the transition you just said?

Comment: I could not put an answer to that in the comment (it was too long) - so I edited my answer above and added one option. However, there are zillions of ways you could do that in Flutter :-) : You could move it around with a Positioned widget, use FadeTransition or SizeTransition or any other Transition.

Comment: thanks I understand the solution