Changing the text of the Appbar while scrolling in flutter

I was able to do this using offset
But I ran into a problem
I have variable sizes of items and they change, so I didn't know the exact size to do this
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  String _appBarTitle = "Hello Amir";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
  }

  void _scrollListener() {
    double offset = _scrollController.offset;

    double section1Start = 1;
    double section2Start = 550;
    double section3Start = 1100; 


    setState(() {
      if (offset < section1Start) {
        _appBarTitle = "Hello Amir";
      } else if (offset >= section1Start && offset < section2Start) {
        _appBarTitle = "The first part";
      } else if (offset >= section2Start && offset < section3Start) {
        _appBarTitle = "The second part";
      } 
    });
  }


You'll need to create your own stateful app bar for this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353786/switch-to-a-different-app-bar-on-scroll-flutter
